# Creating distance in time between objects unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would one create time as distance between two objects?

I have a player and an object that has to come towards the player with a speed of 1second, 0.85 seconds, 0.7 seconds and so on. However, I'm unaware of doing this. I have a moving 2D map with the speed of -4 to give the illusion of running upwards:
[image]

The red triangle on the picture is the object that needs come towards the player, it also has a speed of -4. I created this motion using Time.deltaTime so I would work in realtime. With this logic I believed I had to put the object 4F away from the player to create a 1second interval (desiredSeconds * speed).

PlayerScript

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject obstacle;
    public GameObject player;

    public float playerDimensionY;

    public bool isRight = true;
    public bool inAir = false;
    public bool mouseClicked = false;

    public int flyingSpeed;

    float timeStamp1;
    float timeStamp2;

    bool runOnce = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Vector2 sprite_size = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.size;
        Vector2 spriteScale = transform.localScale;

        float sizeAndScaleY = sprite_size.y * spriteScale.y;

        float player_local_sprite_sizeY = (sizeAndScaleY / GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.pixelsPerUnit) * 0.5F;

        playerDimensionY = player_local_sprite_sizeY;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (isRight == true && mouseClicked == true) {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * flyingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        } else if (isRight == false && mouseClicked == true) {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * flyingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && inAir == false) {
            mouseClicked = true;
            inAir = true;

            if (isRight == true) {
                isRight = false;
            } else if (isRight == false) {
                isRight = true;
            }
        }

        if (GameObject.FindWithTag ("Obstacle") != null && runOnce == false) {
            Debug.Log (string.Format("Spawn time: " + timeStamp1));
            runOnce = true;
        }

        timeStamp1 = Time.fixedTime;
        timeStamp2 = Time.fixedTime;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        inAir = false;
        mouseClicked = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collTrig) {
        Debug.Log (string.Format ("Trigger time: " + timeStamp2));
    }
}
```

ObstacleScript:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObstacleScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float constantSpeed;
    public float destroyTime;
    public float obstacleDimensionY;

    private float selfDestroyTime;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        selfDestroyTime = Time.time + destroyTime;
    }

    void Start() {
        Vector2 sprite_size = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.rect.size;
        Vector2 spriteScale = transform.localScale;

        float sizeAndScaleY = sprite_size.y * spriteScale.y;

        float obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY = (sizeAndScaleY / GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.pixelsPerUnit) * 0.5F;

        obstacleDimensionY = obstacle_local_sprite_sizeY;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position += Vector3.up * constantSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Time.time > selfDestroyTime) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

ObstacleSpawn:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObstacleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerScript pScript;
    public ObstacleScript oScript;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject obstacle;

    public float randomSpawnMin;
    public float randomSpawnMax;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", 2F, Random.Range (randomSpawnMin, randomSpawnMax));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (0.05F, 4F, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, player.transform.position + new Vector3 (-0.05F, 4F, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

However, by using timestamps between obstacle spawn and triggering with the character, I got the result of 0.5 interval instead of 1. Because of this I followed to try making it 8F instead of 4F, which should result in my 1 second interval, but it surprisingly gave a 0.86 interval.

I'm very unaware of what I'm missing, but I feel as there might be a flaw in the way I've set up my deltaTime.

Kind regards.

EDIT - Added code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObstacleSpawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerScript pScript;
    public ObstacleScript oScript;

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject obstacle;

    public float randomSpawnMin;
    public float randomSpawnMax;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", 2F, Random.Range (randomSpawnMin, randomSpawnMax));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 
        var diff = (player.transform.position - obstacle.transform.position);
        diff = diff.normalized;
        Vector3 speed = new Vector3 (100 * Time.deltaTime, 100 * Time.deltaTime, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        diff.x *= speed.x;
        diff.y *= speed.y;
        diff.z *= speed.z;
        obstacle.transform.position = obstacle.transform.position + diff;

    }

    void Spawn() {
        if (pScript.isRight == true && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, obstacle.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        } else if (pScript.isRight == false && pScript.inAir == false) {
            obstacle.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Instantiate (obstacle, obstacle.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var diff = ( Player.transform.position - RedTriangle.transform.position    );
diff = diff.normalized;
var speed = Vector3(1*Time.deltaTime,1*Time.deltaTime,1*Time.deltaTime); // <- speed
diff.x *= speed.x;
diff.y *= speed.y;
diff.z *= speed.z;    
RedTriangle.transform.position = RedTriangle.transform.position + diff;
```

Something like this needs to go in Update of a script.  ( it will move the triangle towards the player )

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please elaborate to give me an understanding?

Comment: I need you to elaborate this - how do I use this piece of code, and where do I put it? Currently I tried placing it in the ObstacleSpawn script in the Start() function, but I get an error: Assets/Scripts/ObstacleSpawn.cs(21,29): error CS0019: Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Vector3' and `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Comment: Hi WONDEREGG - The code was just an example , i forgot Unity doesnt support multiplying two vectors. you need to multiply .x,.y,.z - the code needs to be put in Update.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - However, I tried messing around with the code, and no matter what properties I give the speed, I always receive the same distance between my two objects of 0.2 seconds

Comment: forget my previous comments, I messed around a bit too much. I figured I can only use deltaTime for precesion, but I still only get a .02 time interval, unchangeable. Suggestions?

Comment: Multiply speed with something like this  var speed = Vector3(25*Time.deltaTime,25*Time.deltaTime,25*Time.deltaTime);

Comment: tried messing around with those numbers, all between 1-100, no difference. I got an unkown error with "var speed", so I changed that to Vector3 Speed = new Vector3(). I suppose this could be an issue with current results?

Comment: Edit: Two errors, either I only get a 0.02 interval, or it seems like the triangle spawns the completely wrong place, I added code so you can see what it looks like atm.